# Continuity of a function with product topology

Tags: general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces

Let $f:X\to Y$ be an application of topologies. Consider the set $$\Gamma_f=\{(x,f(x))|x\in X\} \subset X \times Y$$ with the product topology on $X \times Y$.
Prove that $f$ is continuous $\iff$ $\Psi:X \to \Gamma_f, \Psi(x)=(x,f(x))$ is an homeomorphism.

I have a question about the implication "$\Longleftarrow$":
If $\Psi$ is an homeomorphism, in particular $\Psi$ is a continuous application. Now ,assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are topologies induced by the distances $d_1$ and $d_2$, for the continuity of $\Psi$ I have $\forall \epsilon>0$ $\exists \delta>0:$ if $d_1(x,\bar x)<\delta\implies d_2(\Psi(x),\Psi(\bar x))<\epsilon$ this implies the continuity of $f$. The problem is that I am supposing that $X$ and $Y$ are metric topologies... Is there a more general way to prove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider an open subset $V\subset Y$. Now:

$x\in\ f^{-1}(V)\Leftrightarrow f(x)\in V\Leftrightarrow (x,f(x))\in \Gamma_f\cap(X\times V)\Leftrightarrow\Psi(x)\in\Gamma_f\cap(X\times V)$

$\Leftrightarrow x\in\Psi^{-1}\big(\Gamma_f\cap(X\times V)\big)$, so $f^{-1}(V)=\Psi^{-1}\big(\Gamma_f\cap(X\times V)\big)$.

$X\times V$ is open in the product topology, so $\Gamma_f\cap(X\times Y)$ is open in the induced topology. Since $\Psi$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(V)=\Psi^{-1}\big(\Gamma_f\cap(X\times V)\big)\subset X$ is open.

Therefore $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 4):

In this case, $f$ is continuous as a composition of continuous functions:

$$f:X\overset{\Psi}\to\Gamma_f\overset{\text{inc}}\hookrightarrow X\times Y\overset{\text{pr}_2}\to Y$$